# CiviCase Timelines with Activity subjects

Tags: activities, civicase

It would be great if, when creating a new timeline for a Case type, the "Add Activity" dialog could display the activity **subject** field for input. At the moment, if you want to differentiate between activities in the timeline, you have to create different activity types. In many cases, this is overkill - we could use many instances of the same activity type with different subject content.

For example, if I want to include activities in the timeline for completing six different case milestones, I currently have to create six different activity types - one for each milestone. Much better if I could just add six instances of a single activity type called Case Milestone, changing the subject for each instance of the activity type in the timeline.

Also, I would like to be able to update the milestone names in the timeline without having to change the activity types.

Or maybe there's another way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, this seems like an old post that's already resolved in the current CiviCase. Hopefully someone can close this or mark as resolved.