# Default Activity Subject

Tags: civicase

Is it possible to set a default subject for specific Activity types?

We would like to set a default text on the “subject” of each activity that can be created for a case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22735/civicase-timelines-with-activity-subjects

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Vijailakshmi AFAIK you can not set a default for an activity type subject without coding. If you do have some PHP skills it is fairly easy though :-) Let us know and we will detail what needs to be done.